# Use KDE4 with Xenial 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, package-management, kde

KDE 5 is missing critical features for my purposes.  I would like to move some of my systems from 14.04 to 16.04 but wish to hold back to KDE 4.  As best I can tell, this is not practical or at best, extremely difficult to manage administratively.

I wonder if anyone has accomplished this or something similar and would be willing to advise me regarding feasibility and pitfalls?

I recognize that this can be interpreted as an open-ended question, and I'm not seeking an open-ended discussion, but rather, some definitive statements from people who have accomplished this successfully (or know how to) - or the opposite.